# Why is BigDecimal("20") not equal to BigDecimal("2E+1")

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I can understand that in BigDecimals 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 because 2.00 actually uses more precision digits. What I struggle to understand is why `2E+1` is not considered to be equal to `20` because both numbers actually use the same amount of precision digits. IMHO they are merely a different representation of the exact same number.

I know, I can use `stripTrailingZeros` and `compareTo` instead of `equals`, I'm just interested in the reasoning behind this. Can someone maybe help me to understand this?

Comment: Your assumption that `2E+1` and `20` have the same precision is wrong. `2E+1` has one digit precision, whereas `20` has two digits precision.

Comment: [`compareTo` alone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) compares BigDecimals by numerical value, but not [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: @Pieter12345 No. 20 has 0 digits, and 2E+1 has -1 digits.

Comment: @Michael correct. But is this a pure technical point or is there actually any difference in those numbers?

Comment: @Michael You are mixing up scale and precision. Pieter was correct and you can just print the values of `new BigDecimal("20").precision()` and new `BigDecimal("2E+1").precision()` to see that it will print 2 and 1 respectively. At least on my machine.

Comment: `new BigDecimal("2E+1")` has a precision of 1, meaning that it can stand for any number n where 20 <= n < 30, which is not that same as `new BigDecimal("20")` which has a precision of 2 and can therefore only stand for a number x where 20 <= x < 21

Comment: Also note that `new BigDecimal("2.0E+1")` **has** a precision of 2 and therefore `new BigDecimal("20").equals(new BigDecimal("2.0E+1"))` returns true

Comment: Thank you, I think I now now where I went wrong: 2E+1 is not “just” scientific notation for 2*10^2=20 but it actually means something different in BigDecimal, i.e. 20 <= n < 30 as @ThomasKläger pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of scale.

```java
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("20").scale()); // 0
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("2E+1").scale()); // -1
```

BigDecimal considers numbers that are numerically equivalent but with different scales as not being equal.

Comment: From the docs "For example, a scale of -3 means the unscaled value is multiplied by 1000."

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this in the equals method of BigDecimal `if (scale != xDec.scale)` but that still left my with the question _why_.

Comment: @JanGassen "*I can understand that in BigDecimals 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 because 2.00 actually uses more precision digits*" For exactly the same reason as that example you gave in the question.